# How do I get rid of this weird gray drop shadow thing on my EditTexts?

Tags: android

I'm not even sure what it's actually called.. but it looks really bad on some devices.

[image: weird gray thingy]

Comment: if you dont want shadow just add android:background="#ffffff" to the edittet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply your own resource for your EditTexts. Just make your nine patch include it in your drawables folder and use

android:background="@drawable/yourResource"

to set it from your xml.